# Get Folder by Id

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder

How to get folder by ID (GUID) and **navigate** to it? Or with internal (auto-incrementing) ID?

[https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/_api/web/getFolderById('xxxxxxxx')](https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/_api/web/getFolderById(%27xxxxxxxx%27)) works but I would like to NAVIGATE to the folder.

https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=xxxxx doesn't work.

Comment: There is no way to navigate to folder by ID, only by folder URL. On the other hand , you can open forder display card using ID, like `Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=xxxx`

Comment: :/ Thanks for the info!